# In CSS/HTML, how to combine a navigation bar with the content so that the navigation bar is on top the content

Tags: html, css

If you look at this theme, http://itheme-theme.blogspot.com/p/advertise.html, that's basically what I am looking for. In the navigation bar in that theme "Home, About, Support, Contact" etc, it is combined but right above the content. How can I do this?

Sample Code:

---

### HTML.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>

<style>
@import url(css.css);
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="header"></div>

<div id="nav"></div>

<div id="content"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
```

### CSS.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body 
{
}

#header
{
}

#nav
{
}

#content
{
}

#footer
{   
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="nav"></div>

<div id="content"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Do this:

```
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="nav"></div>
  ...Rest of Content Here...
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

This will make your `nav` be on top of the rest of your `content` Although, this isn't exactly necessary in order to achieve what you want. you could always just ensure there are no margins between the `div` elements...